# Java Hibernate Criteria orderBy property or a subclass's property (subclass may be null)

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have two classes with the following structure:

```
class SuperItem{
    SubItem subItem;
    Date dateCreated;
}

class SubItem{
    Date dateModified;
}
```

Sometimes, the property 'subItem' will be null in a SuperItem Object.

I wish to order a list of SuperItems by the most recent values of either dateCreated or subItem.dateModified as lastRecentActivity.

Below is some of what I've tried:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(SuperItem.class);

criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add((Projections.property("subItem").equals(null))?
            Projections.property("dateCreated").as("lastActivity"):
            Projections.property("subItem.dateModified").as("lastActivity")));

criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("lastActivity"));
```

Of course, this is incorrect. But does anybody know of a way to correctly order this?